# Loading / Saving a List of Interfaces

Tags: c#, interface, save, load

In my application I use a list of objects implementing my **ISorter** interface with exposes a single method **void Sort(MyClass myClass)**

So far ive created this list at the entry point on my application with a hardcoded set of **ISorter** implementations. Now im at the point where I'd like to be able to save and load this list from file.

I'd like the format to be XML so that it can be hand edited, but i discovered that .NET **XMLSerializer** class cannot serialize Interfaces. It can serialize a list of base classes, providing I mark the baseclass with the appropriate attributes:

```
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlInclude(typeof(MyClassA))]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlInclude(typeof(MyClassB))]
class MyBaseClass
```

I dislike this, as it clutters my class with xml specific attributes, when i may wish to replace xml serialization with a different storage method later.

1. What is the downside to replacing my **ISort** interface with a **SortBase** baseclass, to facilitate serialziation? Is the use of an interface here wrong to begin with? Should i keep the interface, but implement it using a **SortBase** class from which all my other classes derive?
2. How could I abstract the storage so that the storage implementation could be changed later, and avoid decorating my classes with xml attributes?
3. Any additional information on best practices pertaining to datastorage/loading would be helpful

EDIT: The idea is that a user can create an text file (atm XML is preferred) specifying sorting operations which can the be loaded and applied to the data set.

EDIT2: I have, simplified, this situation

```
class Foo{
   List<ISorter> MySorters
}

interface ISorter{
   void Sort(MyClass myClass)
}

class SortByColor : ISorter{
   public string SomeColorProperty{get;set;}
   void Sort(MyClass myClass)
}

class SortByName: ISorter{
   public string SomeNameProperty{get;set;}
   void Sort(MyClass myClass)
}
```

Id like to pass my **List** to some storage/loading method which can create/load the list from some underlaying datasource ( for example an XML file)

EDIT3:
Ill probably end up using **DataContractserializer**, or **XMLSerializer** as this solves my issue, as long as i provide a common base class. I had expected there to be some more elegant way this could be handled, without polluting my objects with attributes

Comment: How about storing it in Json format and use a JsonSerializer?

Comment: Slightly off-topic, but It sounds like you are trying to do the work that a "dependency injection container" does for you. Have you looked into things like [Autofac](https://autofac.org/)?

Comment: When you "deserialize" an interface, what class to you expect it to create an instance of? What you appear to want is to serialize a set of classes which implement your interface. I mean, how many interfaces do you have? You mention one. Were you planning to deserialize "ISorter, ISorter, ISorter, ISorter, and ISorter"? It would be silly to replace your interface with a base class in any case. It might be handy to write a base class for implementations, though.

Comment: @MatthewWatson Even if I use DI, I still would need some sort of Interface which different storage methods would implement

Comment: @EdPlunkett Yes i want to serialize a list, holding objects that implement the ISorter interface ( SortByColor, SortByName etc etct)

Comment: @AzharKhorasany I'm not sure how this is relevant?

Comment: @ClaudeHasler Then do so. It doesn't matter what interfaces they implement.

Comment: Wait, do you want to serialize the _objects_ or their _fully qualified names_? If the former, "XML  so that it can be hand edited" doesn't make too much sense.

Comment: @EdPlunkett Im looking for best practices of doing so, preferrably in a way which is agnostic to the actual serialization method used.

Comment: @Fildor The ideas is that someone can create a set of sorting operations via xml file, providing they know the xml structure / name required, which can then be loaded and applied to the data

Comment: So, actually you want a configuration file for what i understand.

Comment: @ClaudeHasler "...create a set of sorting operations via xml file..." -- that's a cool idea. I wish you had mentioned it in your question. If you want to talk about agnosticism, I would write that Sort Description Format to be fairly agnostic about the underlying classes and interfaces that implement it. I'd publish the API and let people extend it with their own classes, but I'd keep that well apart from the sort definition file.

Comment: @Fildor essentially yes.

Comment: You need a way to map implementations to an interface - that's what DI containers can help with. But of course, somewhere there will have to be a concrete implementation of the interface.

Comment: Let's ask differently: Do you have some sort of DI in place already? Maybe we can work from there? Most DI frameworks have built-in support for config files. See https://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configuration/xml.html, https://github.com/ninject/ninject.extensions.xml , ...